# How to speed up convolution like function in Python?

Tags: python, performance, opencv, optimization, convolution

I am using the convolution code from [here](https://github.com/whydna/Deep-Learning-For-Computer-Vision/blob/master/convolutions.py) but instead of having the result of the convolution be `k = (roi * K).sum()` I want to be able to change the operation applied to the `(roi * K)`. For instance: `np.std(roi * K)` or `min(roi * K)`.

Unfortunatelly this code is not optimized to run fast, and I wanted it to go faster.

I tried to find an already implemented method like this but I didn't find any. If there is anything like this out there with fast execution that would be great. If not what would be the best strategy to optimize this code?

Tweaking the code a bit to print the execution time this is the result:

```
[INFO] applying small_blur kernel
Convolve Time: 2.21276
OpenCV Time: 0.00088
Ratio Convolve/OpenCV: 2519.95248
[INFO] applying large_blur kernel
Convolve Time: 2.50598
OpenCV Time: 0.00611
Ratio Convolve/OpenCV: 410.16292
[INFO] applying sharpen kernel
Convolve Time: 2.10106
OpenCV Time: 0.00027
Ratio Convolve/OpenCV: 7750.65084
[INFO] applying laplacian kernel
Convolve Time: 2.10883
OpenCV Time: 0.00019
Ratio Convolve/OpenCV: 11111.88317
[INFO] applying sobel_x kernel
Convolve Time: 2.16267
OpenCV Time: 0.00021
Ratio Convolve/OpenCV: 10474.46882
[INFO] applying sobel_y kernel
Convolve Time: 2.09571
OpenCV Time: 0.00022
Ratio Convolve/OpenCV: 9513.05519
[INFO] applying emboss kernel
Convolve Time: 2.10961
OpenCV Time: 0.00026
Ratio Convolve/OpenCV: 8125.21671
```

Comment: Why not just use OpenCV convolution --- filter2D?  See https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d or https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/. In OpenCV, you can even use GPU to make it even faster.

Comment: @fmw42 I don't see how this `filter2D` would solve the problem. The kernel must be a "single-channel floating point matrix" not a function I pass to it.

Comment: Can you not convert your function into a set of kernel elements?

Comment: I am not sure if thats possible. What would you do to transform `np.std()` into a set of kernels?

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand. All the kernels K in the reference you link are 2D matrices. I do not understand how or why you want to use a function. What do you mean or expect from `np.std(roi * K)`. Can you explain functionally what you are trying to do? Do you simply want the standard deviation of each pixel in the roi using a give neighborhood size?

Comment: What I want is instead of having `.sum()` in line 29 of the code linked, I want any python function applied to the region of interest. What is it you do not understand specifically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197466/discussion-between-gustavo-maia-and-fmw42).

Comment: I do not understand what is "any python function". Again, explain what kind of function you want to apply in the roi? In your one example, do you simply want the standard deviation of each pixel in the roi using a give neighborhood size?

Answer (score 2):

You can try looking at [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.12/tutorial_numpy_and_numba.html)

Numba translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime using the industry-standard LLVM compiler library. Numba-compiled numerical algorithms in Python can approach the speeds of C or FORTRAN.

> If your code is numerically orientated (does a lot of math), uses NumPy a lot and/or has a lot of loops, then Numba is often a good choice. In these examples we’ll apply the most fundamental of Numba’s JIT decorators, @jit, to try and speed up some functions to demonstrate what works well and what does not.

You can install it by

```
$ pip install numba
```

and usage is as simple as calling the `@jit` decorator on top of your functions.

Comment: So in the case I have a method using OpenCV I should try to change it to Numpy and then use Numba? Or is it going to speed it up by just adding the `@jit` decorator anyway?

Comment: Numba basically speeds calculations up. Although i am not 100% certain but you can try it on the opencv function first without converting it to numpy.

Comment: I tried with both OpenCV and Numpy but it returns an error (I don't remember exactly what the error was right now but it was something related to compatibility). The error was on the `np.pad()` and the `cv2.copyMakeBorder()` functions.